# Windows host file or similar force IE servername to full domain

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-xp, dns

Have a server on our network that runs a webservice so when you go to URL it shows as http:\myserver

Can I use the hostfile of something similar to force the URL to display as http:\myserver.domain.com

??? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DNS record that points the server's IP address to the name you want to use in the URL.

Comment: The server IP isnt seen. Currently the user shows as http:\\myserver I need to force this to http:\\myserver.domain.com dont think a hostfile DNS IP entry will help this?

Comment: Sure it will. You have to get the IP address of the server, then use it to create a DNS record that points the name you want to use (myserver.domain.com) to that IP address. Then people will type `http://myserver.domain.com` to hit your web service.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following in your .htaccess should do the trick without creating a redirect loop:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^SERVER$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://SERVER.domain%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It may need a bit if tweeking, but it's how I would do it.